# How to add logo into loading screen in my React-Native [Android] project?

Tags: react-native

I'm newbie in React Native.
When I running my project it show a page look like this.

[a snapshot screen in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5KqN.jpg)

I want to replace this blank logo with my logo image. But I have no idea how to do that.
Can anyone help me please.

ps. I run my project in Android, using create-react-native-app to create project and using react-native run-android to run project on my Android phone.

Comment: btw, welcome to stackoverflow 

Comment: are you using Expo?

Comment: @YamanKATBY Not sure, but I think yes. I using 'create-react-native-app' to initialize my project. Compile and run with 'react-native run-android'. It running with Metro cli. But I think it using Expo as background runtime because I always have seen 'Expo' keywords when I running project for many time.

Answer (score 0):

Open your app.json and add the following inside of the "expo" field:

```
"splash": {
  "image": "./assets/splash.png"
}
```

Refer to this official documentation for more customizations and other details: [link](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/splash-screens/)